# ESD protection device impact on SPI

Tags: spi, esd

I have these [ESD](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/littelfuse-inc/PESD0402-140/PESD0402-140CT-ND/1968526) protection devices on my SPI lines. Now, my SPI clock is at approx 4MHz. I go as high as 20MHz.

The datasheet states the following -

[image]

It shows 0.1pF at 1MHz. Will this capacitance increase at higher frequencies ? WIll it affect my system (SPI) ?

Comment: Link is, uh....

Comment: These are very low capacitance polymer ESD protection devices, they are used on much higher frequency data lines than your SPI bus without problems.  Look at the capacitance vs. frequency curve and the eye diagram in the data sheet.

Comment: A more interesting question is why do you need ESD protection on an SPI bus? They tend to be fairly well contained in a single PCB, so just poking on the premise a little...

Comment: Some devices will give a minimum acceptable capacitance and rated speed for the bus. You also need to know the impedance of all devices\pins on the bus to find this one out. Its a fanout thing and more info is required. Usually its best to do a minimum or maximum bound and do some thought experiments to see if it would be a problem.